# jquery how to create an array based on row columns input values

Tags: jquery

I have a table with the following columns:

```
 <tr>
    <td><input data-type="col1" data-id="23" type="checkbox" checked="checked" ></td>
    <td><input data-type="col2" data-id="23" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input data-type="col3" data-id="23" type="checkbox" checked="checked" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input data-type="col1" data-id="45" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input data-type="col2" data-id="45" type="checkbox" checked="checked" ></td>
    <td><input data-type="col3" data-id="45" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td><input data-type="col1" data-id="51" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input data-type="col2" data-id="51" type="checkbox" ></td>
    <td><input data-type="col3" data-id="51" type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
```

Based on the above rows I would like to get the following output:

```
[
{'id': 23, 'col1': true, 'col2': true, 'col3': false},
{'id': 45, 'col1': false, 'col2': true, 'col3': false}, 
{'id': 51, 'col1': false, 'col2': false, 'col3': true}
]
```

> Any clue? Does .map works for this?

Thanks

Comment: Why is 'col2' true and 'col3' false for id 23?

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method.

```
// get all `tr` and iterate over to generate the array
var res = $('table tr').map(function() {
  // generate the object
  return {
    id: $('td:first input', this).data('id'),
    col1: $('td:nth-child(1) input', this)[0].checked,
    col2: $('td:nth-child(2) input', this)[0].checked,
    col3: $('td:nth-child(3) input', this)[0].checked
  };
// get the result as array from the jQuery object
}).get();
```

```js
// get all `tr` and iterate over to generate the array
var res = $('table tr').map(function() {
  // generate the object
  return {
    id: $('td:first input', this).data('id'),
    col1: $('td:nth-child(1) input', this)[0].checked,
    col2: $('td:nth-child(2) input', this)[0].checked,
    col3: $('td:nth-child(3) input', this)[0].checked
  };
// get the result as array from the jQuery object
}).get();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col1" data-id="23" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col2" data-id="23" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col3" data-id="23" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col1" data-id="45" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col2" data-id="45" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col3" data-id="45" type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col1" data-id="51" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col2" data-id="51" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col3" data-id="51" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to generate based on the `data-type` attribute then do something like this using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

```
// get all `tr` and iterate over to generate the array
var res = $('table tr').map(function() {
  // initialize object
  var obj = {
    id: $('td:first input', this).data('id')
  };
  // iterate over the input element and add properties
  // based on the data-type attribute
  $('td input', this).each(function() {
      // define object property
      obj[$(this).data('type')] = this.checked;
    })
  // return the generated object reference
  return obj;
  // get the result as array from the jQuery object
}).get();
```

```js
// get all `tr` and iterate over to generate the array
var res = $('table tr').map(function() {
  // initialize object
  var obj = {
    id: $('td:first input', this).data('id')
  };
  // iterate over the input element and add properties
  // based on the data-type attribute
  $('td input', this).each(function() {
      // define object property
      obj[$(this).data('type')] = this.checked;
    })
    // return the generated object reference
  return obj;
  // get the result as array from the jQuery object
}).get();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col1" data-id="23" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col2" data-id="23" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col3" data-id="23" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col1" data-id="45" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col2" data-id="45" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col3" data-id="45" type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col1" data-id="51" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col2" data-id="51" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-type="col3" data-id="51" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Plain Javascript....

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input[type='checkbox']"),
    arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].checked){
        arr.push(inputJSON(inputs[i]));
    }
}

function inputJSON(elem){
    if (elem.checked){
        var col1 = elem.getAttribute('data-type') == "col1" ? true : false,
            col2 = elem.getAttribute('data-type') == "col2" ? true : false,
            col3 = elem.getAttribute('data-type') == "col3" ? true : false;

        return {'id': elem.getAttribute('data-id'), 'col1': col1, 'col2': col2, 'col3': col3 }
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```